# Pine Script built-in variables not changed when day trading ends earlier than usual. Is this a bug? End of day detection reliability in the last bar

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I would like to program an algorithm that, as part of its operation, detects trading day changes; sometimes it is to do an action just before the trading day ends, and sometimes to do it just after it starts. The algorithm is intended to work on normal time-based charts, and on intraday frames.

After reviewing the PineScript documentation I have seen that there are some variables that could help me with this, one is [`time_tradingday`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_time_tradingday) (plus [`ta.change()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dchange) function to detect if there has been a change in the value of the variable between the current candle and the previous one) and the others are [`session.isfirstbar`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar), [`session.isfirstbar_regular`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar_regular), [`session.islastbar`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dislastbar) and [`session.islastbar_regular`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dislastbar_regular).

Well, I have detected that when the trading hours are restricted (on holidays) the variables do not seem to work correctly or, at least, as I would expect. What I would expect is that if the day starts or ends early, the first/last bar of the time restricted session will be marked as such, even if they are not at the usual time. However, they are ignored. In practice this means that the algorithm mixes two days together as one.

I include a small demo code and screenshots that show as an example. This code plots:

- A red "R" if the last regular bar is detected
- A green "R" if the first regular bar is detected
- A red "E" if the last extended bar is detected
- A green "E" if the first extended bar is detected
- A red (offset -1 bar) and a green "D" if change of trading day is detected on first bar of the new day.

---

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at 
https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © x1900390

//@version=5
indicator("IBO Trading Day Change Detection Possible Bug Demo", overlay=true)

// `session.islastbar` and `session.islastbar_regular` won't change if previous trading day ends earlier than usual.
// Perhaps `session.isfirstbar` and `session.isfirstbar_regular` won't change if trading day starts before usual. (I didn't checked that.)
plotchar(session.isfirstbar, "First Extended Session Bar", "E", location.abovebar, color.green)
plotchar(session.islastbar, "First Extended Session Bar", "E", location.abovebar, color.red)
plotchar(session.isfirstbar_regular, "First Regular Session Bar", "R", location.belowbar, color.green)
plotchar(session.islastbar_regular, "First Regular Session Bar", "R", location.belowbar, color.red)

// `time_tradingday` won't change if previous trading day ends earlier than usual.
tradingDayHasChanged = ta.change(time_tradingday)
plotchar(tradingDayHasChanged, "Change of Trading Day", "D", location.bottom, color.green)
plotchar(tradingDayHasChanged, "Change of Trading Day", "D", location.bottom, color.red, -1)
```

I have observed this behavior in the continuous futures of the S&P500 (ES1!), which is the one I am studying. If we go to May 30th 2022, which ended earlier due to being a holiday, the limits between 27th and 30th are detected and therefore drawn correctly on the chart. However, the limits between 30th and 31st do not, since the session on the 30th ended earlier than usual (even though the chart does display the vertical session separator correctly):

[ES1!_2022-05-27to30 regular hours and change detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKWbd.png)

[ES1!_2022-05-30to31 trading hours ends earlier and change NOT detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCvvd.png)

I would like to confirm if this is a Pine Script bug (which is what I think) or, if not, know how to *reliably* detect end of day **in the last bar, just before the trading day ends** (for instance, to close positions before market closes to avoid gaps).

Comment: It also happens in other pairs. Another example, with Comex gold futures 2022 jun contract (TradingView ticker "GCN2022"). In this case behavior is more erratic: Sometimes last bar work, but day change do not and viceversa.

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ur26.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS1KU.png
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tew0m.png

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is intended. If you check the Pine Reference for the `session.islastbar` and `session.islastbar_regular` functions, you'll see that this is explicitly mentioned in the Remarks:

```
This variable is not guaranteed to return true once in every session because the last bar of the session might not exist if no trades occur during what should be the session's last bar.
```

While retroactively, it is easy to pinpoint what bar would be last on the chart, you would not be able to do so in realtime. If the session is supposed to close on 17:00, but the actual last 1m bar appeared at 16:45, on realtime, you would have no way of knowing that no new bars will appear for the next 15 minutes.

Returning `true` on historical data in such cases would lead to results that would be misleading because they could not be replicated in actual realtime trading. Additionally, these results would repaint if you were to calculate the script on realtime first (and `session.islastbar` would not be true on the bar for 16:45) and then refresh the page (and it would suddenly become `true`).

Your best bet is to expect `session.islastbar` in your script, but also check if a new `session.isfirstbar` comes before `session.islastbar` does, because this means that the last session closed before the expected time.

Comment: I know the highlight but I understand that it refers to conditions of low liquidity. If I understand correctly, Pine Script is based on bar events, not moments in time, so if there are no ticks, no events are fired.

However, in the event that the session time is going to be different, this is known in advance and therefore it would be possible to determine it correctly on the last bar even in real time. I understand that it is a limit of Pine Script (for now).

Comment: This also doesn't explain why `time_tradingday`, which is queried on the first bar of the session, sometimes doesn't change its value either.